# Use a shell script to rename a number of files depending on their contents

Tags: shell, cpu-word, rename

I'm looking for a way to do the following in a linux shell script (bash):

I've got a series of files named in a random order and delivered to a share on the server.
They all contain a certain identifier name inside the file:
e.g.

`fileabc123.xml` contains the word `PCVendor`
`filedef456.xml` contains the word `PrinterVendor`

In order to process these files in the proper way, I need to find a way/combination of commands to rename the files to a new filename containing the word inside the file, so:

`fileabc123.xml` needs to be renamed to `PCVendor-file123abc.xml`
`filedef456.xml` needs to be renamed to `PrinterVendor-file456def.xml`

This needs to be done automatically from inside a shell script.

I was looking at the following:

```
for i in `ls *.xml`;
do
cat *.xml | grep "PCVendor"
mv $i PCVendor-$i
done
```

But I know that this will rename all of the available files to PCVendor-$i instead
of renaming each file to it's corresponding word.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Thanks,
etquart

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in $(grep -l Vendor *.xml); do
    echo mv "$i" "$(
        awk '/Vendor/{
            for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) {
                if ($i ~ "Vendor$"){print $i; exit}
            }
        }' "$i")-$i"
done
```

**NOTE**

- when tests are OK, remove the `echo` from the script to do it for real
- place the script outside of the xml dir to avoid renaming the script itself
- the script can find any string containing Vendor (even in the middle of a line if it separed by spaces or tabs)
- the script looks only the files containing the pattern **Vendor**
- avoid bad habits like `ls *.xml`; and `cat file | grep`, see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: awesome, thanks! I'll give it a try and thanks for the tip on the ls habit:-)

Comment: The way to thanks here : upvote if the answer is useful, and "accept" it if it fits your needs, that's how this website works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when processing files. The best solution is to move the files to a new directory as well as giving it a better/correct name:

```
PCVendorDir=../PCVendor
mkdir -p "$PCVendorDir"

for i in *.xml ; do
    if grep -q PCVendor $i ; then
        mv "$i" "$PCVendorDir/PCVendor-$i"
    fi
done
```

If you don't move the file to a different folder, the next run of the script will rename `PCVendor-file123abc.xml` to `PCVendor-PCVendor-file123abc.xml`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob
for keyword in PCVendor PrinterVendor FruitVendor; do
    grep -l $keyword !(*Vendor-*).xml | xargs -I X mv X $keyword-X
done
```

The extended glob pattern `!(*Vendor-*).xml` selects all xml files *without* "Vendor-" in the name. So the number of files that grep examines will be reduced at each iteration of the loop.